# Getting a domain error in my arguments when trying to create a normal distribution (.rvs) using array values as mean and standard deviation

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops, distribution

So what I am trying to do is create a code that creates a normal distribution for each index value in list mean_temp, which is why I set up index = 0 as a counter. It is ultimately trying to access each subsequent index value  (0, then 1, then 2...) in lists max_temp and min_temp to create a standard deviation. The second loop is to create a list of random points for each distribution (taken from each distribution individually) and average the values as it goes. The weather_data is a DataFrame being derived from a csv file, and the max_temp, min_temp, mean_temp are columns from the DataFrame that I am converting to arrays.

I am new to Python and coding in general so I would greatly appreciate any feedback! Thanks.

```
mean_temp = weather_data['Mean Temp (°C)']
min_temp = weather_data['Min Temp (°C)']
max_temp = weather_data['Max Temp (°C)']


mean_temp = np.array(mean_temp)
min_temp = np.array(min_temp)
max_temp = np.array(max_temp)

daily_temp_list = []

index = 0
for i in range(len(mean_temp)):
    std = (max_temp[index] - min_temp[index])/4
    data = norm.rvs(mean_temp[index], std, size=10000) 
    mu, std = norm.fit(data)
    random_choices = []
    for i in range(100):
        random_point = np.random.choice(data)
        random_choices.append(random_point)
        daily_random_temp = sum(random_choices)/len(random_choices)
    daily_temp_list.append(daily_random_temp)
    index = index + 1
```

The error is
C:\Users\David\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_distn_infrastructure.py:977: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
cond = logical_and(self._argcheck(*args), (scale >= 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\SCHOOL\Graduate\CIVENG_704_R&R\Monte Carlo for mean temp data.py", line 212, in 
data = norm.rvs(mean_temp[index], std, size=10000)

File "C:\Users\David\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_distn_infrastructure.py", line 979, in rvs
raise ValueError("Domain error in arguments.")

ValueError: Domain error in arguments.

Comment: Difficult to say for certain because you haven't explained where `weather_data` comes from, but my guess is that something is going wrong in the way you have defined `std`. Try printing it out before calling `norm.rvs`, and confirm that it is a positive float or integer?

Comment: Sorry about that Jake, weather_data is a DataFrame and I was trying to pull columns from the DataFrame and assign them to seperate arrays. What you suggested helped - I noticed there was a Nan value being returned at some point in my loop due to missing data in the CSV file I am pulling my data from (I thought it was dealt with).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is the result of an input error.